# how to set a keyed list in tcl?

Tags: tcl

When I am going to use *"**keylset**"* in my code, it is getting an error ***"invalid command name "keylset""***

```
set list1 "a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4"
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $list1]} {incr i} {
    keylset klist [lindex $list1 $i] [lindex $list1 [expr $i+1]]
    set klist
}
puts $klist
```

Please give me some solution.

Comment: `keylset` is a command from the [`TclX`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2017) package..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your code is correct? It gives the result

```
{a 1} {1 b} {b 2} {2 c} {c 3} {3 d} {d 4} {4 {}}
```

Was that what you wanted? If you intended to get

```
{a 1} {b 2} {c 3} {d 4}
```

you should increase the value of `i` by 2 in each iteration (`incr i 2`).

You can get the same result this way (requires Tcl 8.5 or later):

```
set klist [lmap {a b} "a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4" {list $a $b}]
```

or by (requires Tcl 8.6 and the TclX package)

```
keylset klist {*}"a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4"
```

for older versions, this does the same thing:

```
set klist [list]
foreach {a b} "a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4" {
    lappend klist [list $a $b]
}
```

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [{*}](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

For TclX documentation, [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11588) seems to be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

The keyed list commands are part of the TclX extension package.
In order to get them to be present in your script, you have to issue the following command (which will arrange for the relevant shared libraries to be loaded and scripts to be sourced).

```
# Note the lower-case 'x', an annoying inconsistency but too late to fix it now...
package require Tclx

# your script here
set list1 "a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4"
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $list1]} {incr i} {
    keylset klist [lindex $list1 $i] [lindex $list1 [expr $i+1]]
    set klist
}
puts $klist
```

The way you install the extension package will depend on what distribution of Tcl you are using. If you're using Debian (or a derivative of it) you will probably do:

```
sudo apt-get install tclx8.4
```

If you are using the ActiveTcl distribution, you instead do:

```
teacup update
```

That installs the current version of a lot of packages, TclX among them. You may well need to do it in an elevated command shell on Windows, or to prefix with `sudo` on OSX.

If you're on OSX and using MacPorts, `tclx` is in the MacPorts system (and of the right version too).

```
sudo port install tclx
```

As there are many possible distributions, or you could build it from source yourself, you'll need to specify carefully what is your platform and setup if it isn't one of the ones I've listed above.

Comment: i have installed tclx8.4, but still the problem is there.